# Is it possible to scan a QR Code in UI Automator tests for AWS Farm devices testing?

Tags: java, testing, qr-code, android-uiautomator, aws-device-farm

I'm creating UI tests on Android Studio for test my app on AWS Farm. Each time I launch the app I need to scan an authentication QR code. I search a solution to send a picture to the camera, so the app can scan the QR code.

I try it manually and it works but when I send the tests on multiple devices on AWS Farm it would not work anymore and I try to search solution to send a picture to the active camera with UI Automator.

Here is my test, before I launch the app and when it's open I click on "scan QR code". When I run this test it open the camera device.

```java
    @Test
    public void clickQrCode() {
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.textContains("SCAN QR")), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
        List<UiObject2> mObject = mDevice.findObjects(By.textContains("SCAN QR"));
        assertThat(mObject.size(), is(1));
        mObject.get(0).click();
        allowPermissionsIfNeeded();

        // The camera is set to ON and wait a QR code
    }
```

I'm not familiar with this framework and found anything to do what I want. If someone have solution to test the QR code scanning for UI tests, I would appreciate it.

Comment: So the issue is with loading the image on the device? If so how are you exactly doing that locally?

Comment: I do a turn around and create a private session who's accepting input and not using the camera. To enter in the app. Because after I receive an SMS so I need to do the same thing. In the private session I allow an absolute password to test the app. At beginning I wanted to send the app every time the same QR code but I don't find any solution to emulate camera on real AWS devices.